# Redirecting Backlinks

Tags: redirects, backlinks

I am working on Influencer marketing, one of the blogger has written a blog for us but they are linking to our landing page with tracking ids, as well as link redirects before the actual URL is hit, is this good for SEO? I personally dont think so but will like some thoughts.

Comment: Any link to a landing page as opposed to a content page does have less value. Google does try and identify landing pages and while they recognize the value of them, Google prefers content.

Comment: Hi @closetnoc the landing page here is our blog content page, so there is no specific landing page. My main question is about the redirecting backlink and tracking id if they are bad for seo.

Comment: Generally a redirect is not a big deal. More than one can be. As far as the tracking ID, I do not think there would an issue there either.